# Choose interface child by some property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an interface:

```
public interface IPath 
{
    // Some method 
}
```

and I have two classes which are inheriting this interface

```
public class First : IPath { }
public class Second: IPath { }
```

By the way, in some method I need to choose which class to use, First or Second, it depending on one string property (**type**), which I get from database. It looks like:

```
public void SomeMethod(string type)
{
   if (type == "First") { // creating instance of First class }
   else if (type == "Second") { // creating instance of Second class }
   else { ... } 
}
```

Question is: how can I avoid if/else or switch/case constructions and automaticly create the right instance, depending on the string variable?

Comment: You can't. There are factory methods that appear to do this from the outside, e.g. `WebRequest.Create`, but that's because they do it inside themselves. There is no magic to this; just brute force.

Comment: You could use reflection, by getting the `System.Type` related to each `type` then passing that to `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Comment: You could use reflection, but I'm not sure that will be better overall. I think it would be useful if you could describe your specific use case. If it has to do with serializing of data, then some serialization formats can handle the types for you.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a dictionary to map from `string` to `Type` and the use that `Type` and [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-6.0#system-activator-createinstance(system-type)) to create an instance of that type.

Alternatively you could fetch the type using reflection and not need a dictionary at all

```cs
private Dictionary<string, Type> _iPathMapping = new Dictionary<string, Type>
{
    { nameof(First), typeof(First) },
    { nameof(Second), typeof(Second) },
};

// ...

public IPath Create(string path)
{
    var type = _iPathMapping[path];
    return (IPath) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

(You'd want to extend that code with safety checks, see below)

But this is fundamentally a bad solve. The problem to this is that it's harder to pass parameters to constructors and it's unsafe as well, if any of your implementations don't have a parameterless constructor, this will fail, but not with a compiler error, no it will fail during runtime, i.e once a user (or hopefully testers/ automatic tests) ran into the problem. So a better way would be to store a method that's invoked to construct the type instead of using `Activator.CreateInstance`, something like

```cs
private Dictionary<string, Func<IPath>> _iPathMapping = new Dictionary<string, Func<IPath>>
{
    { nameof(First), () => new First() },
    { nameof(Second), () => new Second() },
};

// ...

public IPath Create(string path)
{
    if (_iPathMapping.TryGetValue(path, out var func))
        return func.Invoke();

    return null;
}
```

This solves the problem of parameters for the constructor in that it doesn't throw a runtime exception.
But we still haven't solved the problem of actually passing parameters to the constructor, especially when `First` and `Second` require *different* parameters. The only clean* way to I can think of to handle this in a generic and reusable way is using a Dependency Injection framework/ context to actually construct our instances.

But in general, the if/ else if chain or switch statement isn't necessarily a bad thing, you even see it in some places inside .NET

---

* You *could* replicate the part of a DI framework that's responsible for resolving dependencies for a constructor, but that's just re-implementing the wheel and might as well save the effort needed and just pull in a dependency like [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/)

Comment: If you're using a Dictionary, why not have it store `Func<IPath>` instead of using `Activator.CreateInstance` that can fail if the type doesn't have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: Because the `Activator.CreateInstance` was he first that popped into my mind. I did touch on that using that is bad and can fail and when it does it fails at runtime instead of compile time but I didn't stop to think of an alternative. I edited my question to include your suggestion

Comment: This is much better, though I would have put in some error checking if a random type was asked for (`dict.TryGetValue` and throw a meaningful error if it fails)

Comment: @DavidG - you are right, my bad - I didn't pay attention

Answer (score 2):

I have a shorter version as answer, but I saw "MindSwipe" already offered you one:

```
   Dictionary<string, Type> map = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
   map.Add("First", typeof(First));
   map.Add("Second", typeof(Second));

   var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(map[<your parameter as string>]);
```

Comment: This is the same as the other answer, and see my comment there too.

Comment: If you want with params you can use: Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), param1, param2);

Comment: And if `First` requires different parameters to `Second`?

Comment: Define map var like this for different parameters: Dictionary<string, Tuple<Type, List<object>>> map = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<Type, List<object>>>(); and add the parameter you like in the list

Comment: That's an awful way to solve that problem. See the other answer for a far better option.